# How to find Mac Code from serial number of Lenovo G50-70 I3

Tags: windows-7

I want to find out the MAC CODE of my stolen laptop i-e Lenovo G50-70 having serial number YB05302259.

I am having my all data saved in it. Police is willing to help in locating my laptop but I don't have the Mac Code.

Can anyone guide me how to find the Mac Code?.

Comment: If you don't already have the MAC address there isn't much we can do.  Of course knowing the MAC address also won't help you locate it.  It is triviial to mask the MAC address.

Comment: Is there any specific number or address or code that can track down my machine. The police is having some system with them to locate the machine through some IMEI number or Mac Code/ physical address of wireless card. Thats what they asked me to provide them... can I get it by sending an email to the manufacturer ?is there any support services addressing this specific scenario? Regards

Comment: The serial number is that number.  Of course the serial number can only be used to identify the device not find it, MAC address would only work, if it connected to a network they control.  Manufacture might keep track of that information, but its unlikely, again MAC address cannot be used to locate the device.

Comment: @AijazHussain: Marin Althuis's answer is technically correct. There may still be some record of the mac address on your router if you were using the laptop on your home network. It would depend on which model of router you were using and how it was set up.

Comment: Bro James... I am using a wireless router provided by PTCL the telecommunication company... I can access the router as I am having the password... how to check the previously used data in it? sorry to bother you all bro,s as i am sleepless coz of the valueble data of my last 10 years...

Comment: @AijazHussain see if there is a "system log" or "journal" link somewhere in the router's web interface. Also could you tell us what make/model the router is?

Comment: manufactured by Tenda ADSL modem , model W150D-U... its being provided by PTCL there web is www,ptcl.com.pk.... in settings of router the MAC filter is disabled..

Comment: Bro James ... thank you I found the MAC code details from Router... Bro Andre thank you for your concern ,.. I am highly obliged by the kind of help you all guys provided me in finding the MAC code ... Look after your selves and have a nice day... Thank you in deed

Comment: FWIW, that is why you keep local backups of valuable data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, you cannot find a MAC address using a Serial Number.

> Mac address is related to network card.  Nothing whatsoever to do with
>   Serial Number.
>
> Each network device aka wired or wireless has its own hardwired mac
>   address and this can be changed via software on some models.
>
> A Media Access Control address (MAC address) is a unique identifier
>   assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical
>   network segment. MAC addresses are used for numerous network
>   technologies and most IEEE 802 network technologies, including
>   Ethernet. Logically, MAC addresses are used in the Media Access
>   Control protocol sub-layer of the OSI reference model.
>
> MAC addresses are most often assigned by the manufacturer of a network
>   interface card (NIC) and are stored in its hardware, the card's
>   read-only memory, or some other firmware mechanism. If assigned by the
>   manufacturer, a MAC address usually encodes the manufacturer's
>   registered identification number and may be referred to as the
>   burned-in address. It may also be known as an Ethernet hardware
>   address (EHA), hardware address or physical address. A network node
>   may have multiple NICs and will then have one unique MAC address per
>   NIC.
>
> MAC addresses are formed according to the rules of one of three
>   numbering name spaces managed by the Institute of Electrical and
>   Electronics Engineers (IEEE): MAC-48, EUI-48, and EUI-64. The IEEE
>   claims trademarks on the names EUI-48 and EUI-64, in which EUI is an
>   acronym for Extended Unique Identifier.
>
> For wired and wireless cards that are removable it is often listed on
>   a sticker directly on the device.

[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19460471)

Answer (score 6):

You could try to check your home router for some kind of known devices. Maybe there you can find the MAC address.

Comment: Would work just fine in my case. Just remember that different interfaces have different mac addresses.

Comment: (ISP) Internet Service Provider must have your computers MAC address.

But there are policies and laws which control disclosing such information, which vary from company to company and country to country.

Comment: @vnodkumar1987 The ISP likely only has the MAC address of the user's router - i.e. the device that they actually use to connect to the ISP's network.

Comment: @Random832 thank you, ure taking the words out of my mouth. The only network devices which could "know" your notebook's MAC address are devices your notebook was connected to. If it was an ethernet network, the MAC of your network card, if it was a wireless network, your wifi adapter. Each networking unit has its own MAC. For example, my notebook has MAC addresses from 3 physical devices: Wired ethernet, wireless LAN and bluetooth. So if you have been in other networks than your own, maybe you can get the MAC from there.